# Setting a variable in an Execute SQL task

Tags: ssis

I have an Execute SQL task with an OLE DB source that is running this query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('AppLogin') AS TableID
```

In the Result Set tab, I have Result Name 0 mapped to Variable Name User::TableID.

The task executes, but the variable never gets set. It remains 0.

Answer (score 2):

In the Result set Tab,  Set the ResultName = TableID

Ensure that you verify this query "SELECT OBJECT_ID('AppLogin') AS TableID" by clicking Build Query Button from General Tab in the Execute Sql Task Editor. It should return the expected value for AppLogin Object.

Comment: Running from the query builder returns the table id as expected.

Comment: Have you set the ResultName to TableID in the result set tab? This should solve your problem as you were setting Result Name to 0 earlier.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. But it turned out to be something very different. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the general settings of your Execute SQL task component. Make sure the Result Set is set to "Single Row".

Comment: Result Set is set to "Single Row"

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the constraints. I had an expression and a constraint going into the Update component.[image: Needed the OR on constraints]

Didn't realize that the flow wasn't sequential and that the expression and a constraint still need to be OR'ed.